# How to convert the recorded data on (10Hz) high frequency to (1Hz) low frequency using python?

Tags: python, pandas, noise, pandas-resample

I want to convert the data which is recorded in 10Hz into 1Hz. I saw some solutions and i tried it, DO i need to use resample function?, do i need to convert timestamp into sec or minute something?
My question is I have data in millions of rows when i convert that data 10Hz to 1Hz, data will  get reduced or it will increase?

Would be great if you could help me, Thanks in advance.

| start_timestamp | end_timestamp | interpreted_value | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-11-24 07:14:24.903187 | 2020-11-24 07:14:25.003187 | 5.96875 | 10Hz |
| 2020-11-24 07:14:25.003187 | 2020-11-24 07:14:25.103187 | 6.515625 | 10Hz |
| 2020-11-24 07:14:25.103187 | 2020-11-24 07:14:25.203187 | 7.109375 | 10Hz |
| 2020-11-24 07:14:25.203187 | 2020-11-24 07:14:25.303187 | 7.609375 | 10Hz |
| 2020-11-24 07:14:25.303187 | 2020-11-24 07:14:25.403187 | 8.21875 | 10Hz |

Below is the code i tried :

```
df1=df.resample('1S',on='start_timestamp').mean().dropna()
Or
df1=df.set_index('start_timestamp').resample('20L').mean().dropna()
```

Comment: Why didn't these work? are your timestamps strings or proper timestamp datatypes?

Comment: datatype is datetime ,it is not string. it worked, but i am not sure it is right or not, as my dataframe contains 3,30,000 rows and after this "df1=df.resample('1S',on='start_timestamp').mean().dropna()" command i have got only 30,000 rows.

Comment: the number of rows you'll get is exactly  (start_timestamp[-1] - start_timestamp[0])/timedelta(freq) . If you're not sure just do it on the first 100 rows and check it manually.

Comment: Without sample data, current output and expected output we can't solve your issue. I don't know if you're missing 3000 rows because there are duplicates or nan values in your original data.